# Intersexual competition regarding energy investiture of offspring

Tags: species-identification, reproduction, sexual-reproduction

A while ago I remembered reading about a species that had evolved so that the male sperm cells promoted the energy investiture of the female in this offspring upon fertilisation. Since this was a [r-selected species](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R/K_selection_theory) this hurt the females by reducing the likelihood that they would be able to give birth as many times due to the increased strain and so evolved some method that reduces the energy investiture in offspring.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find references to this and was wondering if anyone here would be able to inform me which species I had likely heard about (or give examples of a similar behaviour), preferably with some references (I'm an academic, so probably able to access paywalled journal articles from the main journals).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. What is a "high" K species? (in what manner is it high?) Are you sure it wasn't seminal fluid? Try searching "effect of seminal fluid on female" (without quotes) and see if that helps. if it doesn't, edit to show what you found (showing research effort is expected on this site; "Nothing" is not accepted.) Try rephrasing the question to m.ake it clearer. Thanks

Comment: by high K I actually meant r-selected (don't work in biology so use the term very rarely and always get it mixed up). I have tried searching intersexual competition and only seemed to get results about macroscopic competition between animals rather then competition at a biochemical level. I did manage to come across t-Haplotype sperm in mice (see https://www.inverse.com/science/selfish-sperm-have-a-deadly-advantage). Most of my searches came up with results that were on a completely different track to what I was looking for, but I'll have to add "seminal fluid" to my searches and see

Comment: I think you'll find a lot more information on that different search.